# Programmatically load the contents of a Product in a particular product type

Tags: drupal-commerce

I am developing an Ecommerce site and I am using Drupal-commerce module for it. I have an issue regarding loading the contents of a product which is: How can I programmatically get the contents of all the products in a particular product type?